Unable to use s3-fs-hadoop plugin in Kubernetes
I'm trying to read files on s3 using Flink 1.18.1. I'm moving plugin jar to /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/ in my Dockerfile. I checked it's OK the plugin is in the right folder but when I'm running my pod I have:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

In the logs by the way there is
[] - Plugin loader with ID found, reusing it: s3-fs-hadoop
[] - Delegation token receiver s3-hadoop loaded and initialized

When I add "hadoop-aws" dependency it works but in my understanding it is redundancy and should work without it ?
Is it classloading problem ? How I can resolve it ? I read the doc but it's still not clear for me.
I'm using:

Flink 1.18.1
Scala 2.12.6

My YAML:
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: flink-test
  namespace: mynamespace
  finalizers:
    - flinkdeployments.flink.apache.org/finalizer
spec:
  image: .../flink/test:v1
  flinkVersion: v1_18
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "4"
    taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction: "0.1"
    classloader.resolve-order: parent-first
    metrics.reporters: prom
    metrics.reporter.prom.factory.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusReporterFactory
    metrics.reporter.prom.port: "9250"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: 2048m
      cpu: 1
  taskManager:
    replicas: 1
    resource:
      memory: 4096m
      cpu: 4
  job:
    jarURI: local:///tmp/myjar-0.0.1.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: stateless  # stateless or savepoint or last-state
    entryClass: com.org.MyMainClass
    args: [...]
  podTemplate:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: flink-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: flink-main-container
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 9999 # UID of a non-root user
            runAsNonRoot: true
          ports:
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 9250
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /etc/keystore
              name: user-cert
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /etc/truststore
              name: ca-cert
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: user-cert
          secret:
            secretName: the-user
        - name: ca-cert
          secret:
            secretName: cluster-cert

---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: flink-test
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  podMetricsEndpoints:
    - port: metrics

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: flink-test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: ingress-nginx-iec
  rules:
    - host: "hostname"
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/flink/flink-test(/|$)(.*)"
            backend:
              service:
                name: flink-test-rest
                port:
                  number: 8081 # Replace with your service port
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - host
      secretName: verysecretname

My Dockerfile:
FROM flink:1.18.1-scala_2.12

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /opt/flink/log/ /opt/flink/conf/ /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop && \
    cp /opt/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/ && \
    chown -R flink:flink /opt/flink/ &&\
    chmod -R 755 /opt/flink/

# You can choose whatever directory you want
WORKDIR /opt/flink/lib

# Copy your JAR files
COPY ../target/scala-2.12/test-0.0.1.jar /tmp/test-0.0.1.jar

Assembly settings:
  assemblyMergeStrategy := {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", "services", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.concat
    case PathList("reference.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }


I figured out. My problem was with hadoop-common dependency and because I tried to access to a file through org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem and org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path so they are conflicted with plugin. Finally using Flink FileSystem and/or flink FileSource.forRecordStreamFormat(...) I can read on s3.
And for plugin activation: via Docker file or using ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS both ways work's fine but we shouldn't mix them together, if we do it we have next error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Delegation token provider with service name s3-hadoop has multiple implementations


Flink provides built-in support for several of the supported filesystem plugins like AWS, S3, Azure, etc. via the ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS environment variable as seen below to ensure it's available:
containers:
  - name: flink-main-container
    ...
    env:
      - name: ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS
        value: flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar

These can vary depending on what specifically you need to target but typically align with the version of Flink that you are targeting (e.g. $plugin-$flinkVersion.jar).

In my understanding It's an alternative way to moving jar from /opt to /plugins because if I have my  flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.18.1.jar in plugins/ folder and I add your suggestion In YAML file I have next error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Delegation token provider with service name s3-hadoop has multiple implementations.

I've just tried to build an image without plugin and to use ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS result: I have the same error as in my initial question. Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

That's interesting. With the ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS and no manual copying over within your image, it should work (I have probably 10 jobs that follow this same pattern using the base Flink image). The error makes it sound like it's not properly recognizing the ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS. Maybe a YAML indentation issue?
